# Watching and running 2 scripts with Node, Concurrently and Typescript causes address in use

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon, concurrently

I'm trying to use concurrently with nodemon and tsc to have 2 TS scripts be watched, and thus my nodemon server updated when something changes, the index.ts is my router and the queue.ts is a worker. I'm using the following package.json

```
"dev": "concurrently -k yarn:watch yarn:serve:*",
"watch": "tsc -w",
"serve:index": "nodemon ./build/index.js",
"serve:queue": "nodemon ./build/queue.js"
```

When running `yarn dev` I get the following error
`[serve:*queue] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000` even though the queue.js file only contains a console.log

In my index.ts file I'm using express as follows

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Running on 3000...');
    console.log('For the UI, open http://localhost:3000/admin/queues');
});
```

This is my queue.ts file

```
console.log('testing');
```

When the script is not running the port is not in use, I check this by running `lsof -i tcp:3000`

Comment: You are running `yarn:serve:*` concurrently. It probably just executes `serve:index` twice.

Comment: @TobiasS. I don't think so, it just runs both the serve: scripts, if I change the syntax to `"dev": "concurrently -k yarn:watch yarn:serve:server yarn:serve:db"` the error persists

Comment: @MiguelStevens try using tsx, `tsx watch index.ts`, tsx had a fix for this error iirc

Comment: @Dimava tsx instead of tsc? Or tsx in stead of concurrently? In which part do I put the tsx command?

Comment: @MiguelStevens `tsx watch file.ts` is equivalent of `nodemon --watch '.' exec 'node --inspect --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm/transpile-only ./file.ts` or something. Basically you just run it on TS file and it works. You'll need concurrently `tsx watch src/index.ts` and `tsx watch src/queue.ts` I guess

Comment: @MiguelStevens https://github.com/privatenumber/ts-runtime-comparison

Comment: @Dimava Thanks! Concurrently is causing issues but I managed to get it running using `tsx watch file.ts & tsx watch otherfile.ts`

Comment: @MiguelStevens please once again check if it was `concurrently` or `nodemod` (IMO nodemon is more likely), so I'll post an answer

Comment: I tried using `concurrently tsx watch index.ts tsx watch queue.ts`, I receive the following errors `/bin/sh: watch: command not found, /bin/sh: src/index.ts: Permission denied, /bin/sh: watch: command not found`